# CakePHP Default values for date select

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a set of selects for a date of birth:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Profile.dob', array('label' => 'Date of Birth'
                                    , 'dateFormat' => 'DMY'
                                    , 'minYear' => date('Y') - 100
                                    , 'maxYear' => date('Y') - 13)); ?>
```

and want to set the defaults to be the words "DAY MONTH YEAR" in the selects.

I have managed to do this with the gender with:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Profile.gender', array('label' => 'Gender', 'type' => 'select',
         'options' => array('Male'=>'Male','Female'=>'Female'),'empty'=>'Select Sex')); ?>
```

but I don't see how to do this with the automagic date input...

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: You could potentially add a few lines of JS to append to the beginning of the <selects> the text? Short of modifying the form helper - I can't think of a less "hackish" way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind 2 more lines, you can try doing this?

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->year('Profile.dob', date('Y') - 100, date('Y') - 13, array('empty' => "YEAR"));
echo $this->Form->month('Profile.dob', array('empty' => "MONTH"));
echo $this->Form->day('Profile.dob', array('empty' => 'DAY'));

?>
```

Comment: Gives me this error: `Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /Users/cameron/Sites/social/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php on line 1816`

Comment: @Cameron, may be I am missing some braces or you wanna try $this->Form->year(....).

Comment: @Cameron, I apologize I should have mentioned. It would work only for cake 1.3+

Comment: This is the correct answer, but on the year() call you should do this: `echo $this->Form->year('Profile.dob', array('minYear' => date('Y') - 100, 'maxYear' => date('Y') - 13, 'empty' => "YEAR"));`

Answer (score 12):

Simply add:

`'selected'=>date('Y-m-d')`

to your array of options.

That example will show the current date. If you need to have a static date, replace it as required. eg:

`'selected'=>'2011-12-10'`

Obviously for the date and time, use:

`'selected'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

or

`'selected'=>'2011-12-10 11:13:45'`

Comment: What about DAY MONTH YEAR as in the actual words!

Comment: 'selected' is the keyword I was looking for, thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 8):

This way works:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->input(
    'Profile.dob', 
    array(
        'label'         => 'Date of Birth',
        'dateFormat'    => 'DMY',
        'minYear'       => date('Y') - 100,
        'maxYear'       => date('Y') - 13,
        'empty'         => array(
            'day'       => 'DAY',
            'month'     => 'MONTH',
            'year'      => 'YEAR'
            )
        )
    ); 
?>
```

Comment: Nice! This exactly answers the original question (which I had as well) and does it without switching to three separate statements.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented it like this in cakephp 2.0 above

```
echo $this->Form->dateTime('dob', 'DMY','', array(
    'value'=>'1987-02-12',
    'empty'=>false,
    'label'=>'Date Of Birth',
    'minYear'=>date('Y')-60,
    'maxYear'=>date('Y')-15)
);
```

'value' attribute has been added after 2.0 api of cakephp and 'selected' is remove.

Cakephp manual says :The $selected parameter was removed from several methods in FormHelper. All methods now support a $attributes['value'] key now which should be used in place of $selected. This change simplifies the FormHelper methods, reducing the number of arguments, and reduces the duplication that $selected created. The effected methods are:

```
FormHelper::select()
FormHelper::dateTime()
FormHelper::year()
FormHelper::month()
FormHelper::day()
FormHelper::hour()
FormHelper::minute()
FormHelper::meridian()
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, are you really sure about what you really mean?

You seem to be confusing default value and empty value. If you set default value as `DAY MONTH YEAR` using 'selected', your code won't work because `DAY MONTH YEAR` isn't a valid date.
Using

```
'empty' => array(
  'day' => 'DAY',
  'month' =>'MONTH',
  'year' =>'YEAR'
);
```

looks like what you're looking for, inviting the user to enter a date.

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp set selected to the empty value if the corresponding date request data is null, therefore simply set it to null prior to echoing the date input fields:

```
$this->request->data['Profile']['dob'] = null;

echo $this->Form->month('Profile.dob', array('empty' => "MONTH"));
// do the same for year and day
```

the empty value (in your case "DATE", "MONTH", "YEAR" fields) will be pre-selected in the input form

Answer (score 0):

This is what currently works for me in cakephp 2.5:

```
echo $this->Form->input('fecha_pos_fijacion', array(
    'label' => 'Fecha de fijación',
    'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
    'minYear' => date('Y'),
    'maxYear' => date('Y')+5,
    'orderYear' => 'asc',
    'selected' => date('Y-m-1')
    )
```

);

This is a bit more elaborated, it'd give you a default value set to the 1st day of current month. Possible values for year are between current and 5 years ahead, displayed in ascending order.

Even more complete:

```
echo $this->Form->input('fecha_transporte', array(
                    'label' => '',
                    'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
                    'minYear' => date('Y'),
                    'maxYear' => date('Y')+5,
                    'orderYear' => 'asc',
                    'selected' => date('Y-m-1', strtotime("+30 days"))
                    )
            );
```

Here default is 1st day of *next* month